M.2 storage, PCIe 3 vs. 4, does it matter IOPS wise?
I am thinking of buying an SM X12STH-F board (chipset C256) which only supports M.2 PCIe 3 — which is a little hard to swallow in December of 2024!
If I install an M.2 PCIe 4 drive (ex: a Samsung 990 Pro), would it make any difference for standard small-business-use (SMB shares, Windows terminal, RDP, and SQL-Server) compared to a board with PCIe 4 support (or at this point, even PCIe 5 for that matter)?
I think the drive will still be the bottleneck IOPS wise and not the PCIe interface; is this correct?

If you use just the "slow" (2,5Gbit/s) onboard Ethernet controller of the mainboard, it doesn't matter. PCIe ver. 3 halves the max speed of your chosen SSD from round about 8 GB/s to 4 GB/s (compared to PCIe ver. 4).
But, I don't recommend using a consumer brand SSD like a Samsung 990 Pro for a 24/7 enterprise application. You should invest into enterprise SSD or expect a system fail within the next 2-3 years. An alternative to an enterprise SSD would be a SSD RAID1 made from 2 consumer SSD, which would increase latency, complexity and power draw, but would still perform worse than the enterprise SSD.

"An alternative to an enterprise SSD would be a SSD RAID1 made from 2 consumer SSD" <-- That's a bad idea, really! See, flash drives don't fail due to mechanical issues like spinners; they fail because the flash cells wear out. Mirrored flash drives will wear out in the same way and fail at the same time. Bottom line: Mirroring flash makes no sense.

Just use 2 different models, it's not so bad and just better than a single consumer SSD as OP tried to use.

@NISMO1968 SSD failure modes include controller malfunction. Mind you, I've seen it, and you can't recover from it — data in the flash is scrambled using AES (in particular, to equalize 0's and 1's to improve the performance of the flash chips FEC algorithm) and the key is stored in the controller, so failed controller = lost data.. The only way to resolve this is to have more than one SSD. Bottom line: always avoid single point of failure if it's about data.


does it matter IO/s wise?

Roughly, it halves the max throughput from 7.9 GB/s for PCIe 4.0 to 3.9 GB/s for PCIe 3.0. It also somewhat halves the max IOPS you can expect.
While that won't matter much for most direct network activity (e.g. SMB share), even with 10G Ethernet, it might for a heavily loaded SQL database. The effect on a database could be countered with more main memory though (which is much faster than any SSD anyway).
It all boils down to what your expected workloads are.

Not that big a difference! I might even be better in some cases.


Single-command performance isn't really a good indication for server storage. Like @paladin has pointed out, consumer-grade SSDs aren't usually a good match for that.

It is a very good match for small-businesses. I have servers been running for 5 years serving 30 people with SMB share, SQL, virtual windows (RDP) Web-server etc. with consumer SSD which hove more than double lifespan left. Not a problem at all.  Just the power-consumption of a enterprise disk by it self makes is a bad choice! Even Backblaze only use consumer disk with huge success. Of course I wouldn't install a consumer-disk in a Azure datacenter. But in many cases enterprise disks is overkill.
